# Gulp - Make multiple copies of a file based on an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have an array of strings (`["red", "green", "blue"]`), and I want my Gulp stream for certain files to individually process and clone files into folders based on the strings.

My source file tree in `./src/stylus/` looks like this:

```
style.styl
util.styl
themes/basic.styl
themes/advanced.styl
```

After Gulp has done its magic, I want my build destination (`./build/css/`) to look like this:

```
style.css
util.css
themes/basic.css
themes/advanced.css
themes/red/basic.css
themes/red/advanced.css
themes/green/basic.css
themes/green/advanced.css
themes/blue/basic.css
themes/blue/advanced.css
```

My Gulpfile currently looks something like this;

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import stylus from 'gulp-stylus';
import flatmap from 'gulp-flatmap';
import postcss from 'gulp-postcss';

var filters = ["red", "green", "blue"];

// ...

gulp.src([
    './src/stylus/**/*.styl',
    '!./src/stylus/**/_*.styl'
])
    .pipe(stylus())
    .pipe(flatmap(function(stream, file) {
        if(file.relative.split("/")[0] == "themes") {
            for(var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
                gulp.src(['./src/stylus/' + file.relative])
                    .pipe(postcss()) /* Some filters[i] specific processing here */
                    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css/themes/' + filters[i] + "/"));
            }
        }

        return stream;
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css'))
    .on("end", cb);
```

The above doesn't seem to throw any errors, but it also doesn't create the `/themes` folder in the build destination.

How can I get this to do what I want?